# Stability of compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, stability

Which is more more stable, *cis*-1-ethyl-3-methylcyclohexane  or *trans*-1-ethyl-3-methylcyclohexane?

I think *trans-* is more stable than *cis-* but in my textbook the answer is different.

Comment: With cis both substituents can be equatorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** This is a homework question, so I will not provide a complete answer (site policy).

Cyclohexane usually exists in the chair-conformation. See the picture below.
[image]

The different substituents on a cyclohexane ring (here they are all hydrogen) can be either *axial* or *equatorial*. Axial substituents point along the axis of the cyclohexane ring, while the equatorial substituents point outward the equator of the cyclohexane ring. I have marked the axial and equatorial positions in red and blue respectively:
[image]
Adjacent axial or adjacent equatorial positions are *trans* with respect to each other. Equatorial positions are considered more stable compared to the axial positions, due to steric factors.

With the knowledge above, you should be able to correctly decide on the answer.